# PythonOCC Basic example not working

Tags: python

Using the basic example on their website:

```
from OCC.Display.SimpleGui import init_display
from OCC.BRepPrimAPI import BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox

display, start_display, add_menu, add_function_to_menu = init_display()
my_box = BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox(10., 20., 30.).Shape()

display.DisplayShape(my_box, update=True)
start_display()
```

I can't get that to run? Any ideas?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\OCC\Display\SimpleGui.py", line 164, in init_display
    win.canva.InitDriver()
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\OCC\Display\pysideDisplay.py", line 79, in InitDriver
    self._display = OCCViewer.Viewer3d(self.GetHandle())
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\OCC\Display\pysideDisplay.py", line 55, in GetHandle
    return int(self.winId())
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PyCObject'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a duplication of a github issue:

https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-core/issues/68

we need to know which GUI library your using and what verion of pythonocc you are one.
this is an older version of pythonocc, the current you can [find here](https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-core/releases):

Why not try and install that newer version?
Its important that the [OCE library](https://github.com/tpaviot/oce/releases) you've got installed match.
So pythonocc-core 0.16 goes with OCE 0.16